# RabbitMQ Quorum Queue - Is the data written to/delivered by only one node?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, raft, quorum

In a RabbitMQ Quorum Queue (using raft) cluster of say 4 nodes (N1-N4),

Can I have a consumer that can read only from N1/N2? In this case, will a message produced in N3, be delivered to a consume via N1/N2?

As per the documentation from the below post:
https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2019-04-03-quorum-queues-internals-a-deep-dive.html

> With Raft, all reads and writes go through a leader whose job it is to
>   replicate the writes to its followers. When a client attempts to
>   read/write to a follower, it is told who the leader is and told to
>   send all writes to that node. The leader will only confirm the write
>   to the client once a quorum of nodes has confirmed they have written
>   the data to disk. A quorum is simply a majority of node

If this is the case, How can scaling be achieved if it's just the leader node that's gonna do all the work?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, RabbitMQ clusters should have an odd number of nodes, so that a majority can always be established in the event of a network partition.

Consumers can always read from *any node* in a RabbitMQ cluster. If a queue master/mirror is not running on the node to which the consumer is connected, the communication will be forwarded to another node.

> How can scaling be achieved if it's just the leader node that's gonna
> do all the work?

"scaling" is so non-specific a word that I hesitate to answer this. But I assume you're asking what happens with multiple quorum queues. The answer is that each queue has its own leader, and these leaders are distributed around the cluster.